# React - Cannot read property 'props' of undefined when clicking button

Tags: react-redux

I would like to be able to click a button and navigate to another page on the site.

I have tried to use the code from this page but cannot make it fit into my code. I have also got this code from another page.

Any help appreciated.

[React route example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

```
import React from 'react';

class Home extends React.Component{
    constuctor() {
        this.routeChange = this.routeChange.bind(this);
      }

    routeChange() {
        let path = '/CreateAccount';
        this.props.history.push(path);
      }      

    render(){
        return(

          <div>
          <p>
                <button         
                onClick={this.routeChange}
                class="btn btn-lg btn-gradient"
                >
                    Signup                        
                </button></p>
          </div>
            )
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the function to the correct `this`. The easiest method is use an ES6 arrow function for `routeChange`. If you don't, the `this` in routeChange is the originator of the click, rather than the component.

Arrow functions are automatically bound to the `this` of the containing instance.

```
routeChange = ()=> {
    let path = '/CreateAccount';
    this.props.history.push(path);
  }
```

There are other ways to solve this problem such as patching it in the constructor:

```
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.routeChange = this.routeChange.bind(this);
  }
```

... but arrow functions are a lot simpler and more convenient imo.